# How to enable parallelism for a custom U-SQL Extractor

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I’m implementing a custom U-SQL Extractor for our internal file format (binary serialization). It works well in the "Atomic" mode:

```
[SqlUserDefinedExtractor(AtomicFileProcessing = true)]
public class BinaryExtractor : IExtractor
```

If I switch off the “Atomic“ mode, It looks like U-SQL is splitting the file in a random place (I guess just by 250MB chunks). This is not acceptable for me. The file format has a special row delimiter. Can I define a custom row delimiter in my Extractor and enable parallelism for it. Technically I can change our row delimiter to a new one if it can help.
Could anyone help me with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is indeed split into chunks (I think it is 1 GB at the moment, but the exact value is implementation defined and may change for performance reasons).

If the file is indeed row delimited, and assuming your raw input data for the row is less than 4MB, you can use the input.Split() function inside your UDO to do the splitting into rows. The call will automatically handle the case if the raw input data spans the chunk boundary (assuming it is less than 4MB).

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/AmbulanceDemos/AmbulanceDemoCode/Class1.cs) is an example:

```
public override IEnumerable<IRow> Extract(IUnstructuredReader input, IUpdatableRow outputrow)
{
   // this._row_delim = this._encoding.GetBytes(row_delim); in class ctor
   foreach (Stream current in input.Split(this._row_delim))
   {
       using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(current, this._encoding))
       {
           int num = 0;
           string[] array = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[]{this._col_delim}, StringSplitOptions.None);
           for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
           {
              // DO YOUR PROCESSING
           }
       }
       yield return outputrow.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Please note that you cannot read across chunk boundaries yourself and you should make sure your data is indeed splittable into rows.

Comment: Thank you Michael for such quick answer! It works for us. Plus we used it for our Avro Extractor, that extracts data from files in Avro format.

Comment: I have an additional question here: can we increase number of vertices allocated for extracting a file with an Extractor? For example U-SQL allocates 3 vertices for extracting data from a 2.5GB file, but we know we can process the file much faster on 8 AU.

Comment: There is currently no way to indicate this. If you feel like this is a missing capability, please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Comment: @ValeriIlyin are you able to share/link to the code for your AvroExtractor? The MS sample has some shortcomings, suhc as the lack of parallelism